# define custom validation in sequelize

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I have the User model with its validations. The only validation that doesn't work is this.

```
User.init({
    confirmation: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        validate: {
            notNull: {
                msg: "Not null"
            },
            areEquals(value) {
                if (value !== this.password) {
                    throw new Error("Not Equals");
                }
            }
        },
    }
    // ...
})
```

`areEquals` is not executed. And it always shows "not null violation" even when sending a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.init({
    confirmation: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
            notNull: false, // this is boolean
            areEquals: (value) => { // Updated 

                console.log(this.password) // while insert new data, password is null

                if (value != this.password) {
                    console.log('**')
                    throw new Error("Not Equals");
                }

                return true // must return true
            }
        },
    },
});
```

Test

```
await db.user.upsert({
    name: '123123123',
    password: '123456',
    confirmation: '3456'
})
```

> ERROR: Validation error: Not Equals,
> Validation error: Not Equals

Comment: what is your test method ?